# Typo3 10.4 How to add available language?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In the guide there is information to use `create new language` button:
[image]

But I don't have this button in 10.4 verions:
[image]

**How to add available language?**

I have read tons of pages in official guidleline, does you know better documentation for Typo3?

Comment: Have you created "Website Language" records on the root level of the page tree? These can then be added as language to a site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a record for each language that should be available in your TYPO3 installation first. To do so, go to the list module, select the root page (the most top page with page id=0) and create records there:

[image]

After that you can add the language to your site as shown in your screenshot.

I've checked the official documentation and it seems that this information is missing. I'll try to get that fixed!

Comment: Thanks, Peter, for taking care of the docs. I also checked BE and documents... Since TYPO3 v11, sys_language entries are no longer required. So, the documentation only has to be adapted for old versions of TYPO3 (or with a note for old versions).

Comment: Pull request for the documentation: https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Reference-CoreApi/pull/1893